# How to convert this dataframe into the following format?

Tags: pandas, datetime, dataframe, matplotlib

I have a .csv file containing a table in the following manner:

```
lon    lat    Day1   Day2   Day3   ....
77.32  28.42  1250   850    680   
77.32  28.88  786    986    760
```

Given a particular lat lon value, say lon=77.32 and lat=28.42, I want to read a row and rearrange it in the following manner:

```
              Albedo Values
11-11-2016      1250     
12-11-2016      850
13-11-2016      680
    . . . . . . . 
    . . . . . . .
```

The 'Day' columns have been replaced by a list of dates.

**Background:**

I want to further plot a line chart from this data. Currently I was trying the following code to plot this data:

```
#relevant imports:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.api as sm

#specifying lat lon value range:

l=float(28.42)
l1=float(28.43)
k=float(77.32)
k1=float(77.33)

#reading the relevant row

df=pd.read_csv(path+file, index_col=['lon','lat']).query( '@k <= lon < @k1 and @l < lat <= @l1').T
print(df)
```

Out:

```
lon      77.328125
lat      28.421875
Day1   1250.250000
Day2    804.250000
Day3    750.000000
Day4    713.875000
Day5    740.650000
Day6    840.250000
Day7    844.200000
Day8   1009.000000
```

^This is the dataframe I am working with right now which is a make shift approach.

```
df.plot(legend=True) #plot column
plt.show()
```

Out:

[image]

As you can see, there are no labels on the x axis, and with the dataframe I am currently using, I am not able add dates on the x axis. I can work this problem out once I get the desired dataframe. Even if you can suggest me a way to add dates on the x axis with this makeshift dataframe itself, my problem will be solved. Hope my problem made sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think need [`melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) and then convert column to `datetime`:

```
df = df.melt(['lon','lat'], var_name='date')

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
print (df)
     lon    lat       date  value
0  77.32  28.42 2016-11-11   1250
1  77.32  28.88 2016-11-11    786
2  77.32  28.42 2016-12-11    850
3  77.32  28.88 2016-12-11    986
4  77.32  28.42 2016-11-13    680
5  77.32  28.88 2016-11-13    760

df.plot(x='date', y='value', legend=True)
```